# Event listener to dynamic HTML not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Using a angularjs directive, I am adding an event listener to a dynamically created HTML element that is inserted into the DOM.

However, the event listener is not triggering. If I add an event listener to the document, it works but it does not seem to be calling the event listener associated with the dynamically added element.

I have created a fiddle for the issue: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BBHzr/).

I create the dynamic element as:

```
button = document.createElement('button');
```

I then add the event listener:

```
button.addEventListener('click', function () {
    alert("Button event listener is called");
});
```

But the event listener is never called.

EDIT: Please note that the directive will be used in multiple locations and I am looking for a solution that does not use classes or IDs but still must uniquely capture the clicks.

Comment: Would it be that you want to iterate through every button on page, and check for a click on each one? Why not store all buttons in a node-list, for-loop through them, and add the event listener within the loop?

Comment: @NickDugger No. I will not be iterating through every button on the page. I want the directive to keep track of the buttons inserted and when the button is clicked, invoke the click handler for that button because based on which button is clicked, I will set the corresponding model. Looping is too intensive.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of:

```
element[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', button.outerHTML);
```

Use:

```
element[0].insertAdjacentElement('afterend', button);
```

**Demo**: http://jsfiddle.net/7nus5/

Comment: This is weird. I had to use `outerHTML` because if I use just button, I get `[Object HTMLButtonElement]` instead of the actual button. Its the exact code as seen in fiddle, yet I get the object instead of the HTML. Any idea why?

Comment: Note that the example is using insertAdjacentElement instead of insertAdjacentHTML.

Comment: I can't thank you enough! I was exhausted yesterday trying to figure this out and did not notice it until you pointed it. Many Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/BBHzr/2/

```
var app = angular.module('Test', []);

app.directive('sampleDirective', function () {
    return function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var button = document.createElement('button');    

        //document.addEventListener('click', function () {
        //alert("Document Event Listener triggered");
        //});

        button.textContent = "Click Me!";

        element[0].insertAdjacentHTML('afterend', button.outerHTML);

        button = document.querySelector("button");

        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            //This never gets called :(
            alert("Button Event Listener triggered");
        });

    };
});
```

You were referencing the creation of the button, and not actually the element on the page for the event listener -- or it was just the order of the code on the page. Either way, it works now.

Comment: While this is indeed a solution, I am afraid it is not the one that I am looking for. With your solution, the event listener is triggered. However, if there are multiple buttons on the page, then all of them will trigger this. I am looking to handle the click event only for the created button and not all buttons on page.

Comment: One solution would be to add a class to the newly created element and then use the class to listen to events but this is not elegant.

Comment: Then simply apply an ID to the button, and use getElementById instead of querySelector. button.setAttribute("id", "myButton");

Comment: This will be on the lines of querying by class, except we query by ID. Still not what I am looking for.

Comment: How is this not what you're looking for? From your question, it's exactly what you're looking for. You may need to be more specific in your question.

Comment: You are correct. I apologise for that and I will edit my question to reflect the requirements more clearly